# Translating date to day of week

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I have a method to translate naming days of week to my native language:

```
def translate_date(daytime)
  case daytime
  when daytime.strftime('%A') == 'Monday'
    'Poniedziałek'
  when daytime.strftime('%A') == 'Tuesday'
    'Wtorek'
  when daytime.strftime('%A') == 'Wednesday'
     'Środa'
  when daytime.strftime('%A') == 'Thursday'
     'Czwartek'
  when daytime.strftime('%A') == 'Friday'
     'Piątek'
  when daytime.strftime('%A') == 'Saturday'
     'Sobota'
  when daytime.strftime('%A') == 'Sunday'
     'Niedziela'
  end
end
```

I use it for example as:

```
date = Sat, 21 May 2016 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
translate_date(date) # => nil
```

Where is the problem with this method? Why does it return `nil`?

Meanwhile, I get:

```
date.strftime('%A') == 'Saturday' # => true`
```

Comment: You might want to consider using internationalization for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking the expression after `case` with the expression after `when` happens like this:

```
daytime === (daytime.strftime('%A') == 'Monday')
# => nil
```

The problem is that you are trying to compare `daytime` after `case` with `nil` after `when`. So, if all `when` return `nil`, all expression returns `nil`.

Use `case` statement correctly:

```
def translate_date(daytime)
  case daytime.strftime('%A')
  when 'Monday'
    'Poniedziałek'
  when'Tuesday'
    'Wtorek'
  when 'Wednesday'
    'Środa'
  when 'Thursday'
    'Czwartek'
  when 'Friday'
     'Piątek'
  when 'Saturday'
    'Sobota'
  when 'Sunday'
    'Niedziela'
  end
end
date = Date.parse("Sat, 21 May 2016 00:00:00 UTC +00:00")
# => Sat, 21 May 2016
translate_date(date)
# => "Sobota"
```

Also, as @AnthonyE mentioned in comments, it is better to use [internationalization](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n) for your goal.

Comment: Well-explained. Sometimes a hash is used instead: `day_map = { 'Monday'=>'Poniedziałek', ... }`, then `day_map[daytime.strftime('%A')]`.

Answer (score 2):

`Case` is not same like `if`
If you wanna use case method, so use it like this

```
def translate_date(daytime)
  case daytime.strftime('%A')
    when 'Monday'
      'Poniedziałek'
    when 'Tuesday'
      'Wtorek'
    when 'Wednesday'
      'Środa'
    when 'Thursday'
      'Czwartek'
    when 'Friday'
      'Piątek'
    when 'Saturday'
      'Sobota'
    when 'Sunday'
      'Niedziela'
  end
end
```

But better way is this

```
DAYS_IN_PL = {
  'Monday' => 'Poniedziałek',
  'Tuesday' => 'Wtorek',
  'Wednesday' => 'Środa',
  'Thursday' => 'Czwartek',
  'Friday' => 'Piątek',
  'Saturday' => 'Sobota',
  'Sunday' => 'Niedziela'
}

def translate_date(daytime)
  DAYS_IN_PL[daytime.strftime('%A')]
end
```

Comment: The "better way" solution that you did is very elegant Ruby.  Nicely done!

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more compact version of translate_date, which also does a conversion to DateTime if the daytime parameter happens to be a String:

```
require 'date'

def translate_date(daytime)
  daytime = DateTime.parse(daytime) if daytime.is_a?(String)
  case daytime.strftime("%A")
  when 'Monday'    then 'Poniedziałek'
  when 'Tuesday'   then 'Wtorek'
  when 'Wednesday' then 'Środa'
  when 'Thursday'  then 'Czwartek'
  when 'Friday'    then 'Piątek'
  when 'Saturday'  then 'Sobota'
  when 'Sunday'    then 'Niedziela'
  end
end

current_date = DateTime.now

20.times do |offset|
  puts "#{current_date.strftime("%F")}: #{translate_date(current_date)}"
  current_date = current_date.prev_day
end
```

This solves the structural issue with your case statement, and makes it far easier to read.

This will output the following:

```
2016-05-16: Poniedziałek
2016-05-15: Niedziela
2016-05-14: Sobota
2016-05-13: Piątek
2016-05-12: Czwartek
2016-05-11: Środa
2016-05-10: Wtorek
2016-05-09: Poniedziałek
2016-05-08: Niedziela
2016-05-07: Sobota
2016-05-06: Piątek
2016-05-05: Czwartek
2016-05-04: Środa
2016-05-03: Wtorek
2016-05-02: Poniedziałek
2016-05-01: Niedziela
2016-04-30: Sobota
2016-04-29: Piątek
2016-04-28: Czwartek
2016-04-27: Środa
```